# Locality of variables in functions and memory

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory, scope

I've done the following:

```
char * copyact(char * from)
{
    return ++from;
}

int main()
{

    char *string = "school";
    char *copy;
    copy = copyact(string);
    printf("%s", copy);
}
```

This is printing `chool`, however my idea is the application must crash when we try to print it in main(). By scope rules, parameter from is a variable local to copyact function. I'm doing from = from + 1; and returning address to that place. So when we get back to main, shouldn't the memory given to that location now be invalid because all local variables must be destroyed? Why is this thing still working?

**Clarification:** Don't we assign a memory location for the pointer &from in which it stores the address for the string? When the function exits, don't we also destroy the address of pointer that holds the valid address? or is it because by the time return is executed, the address it points to was already sent to copy= ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Undefined behavior is not a crash

First of all please remember that when you do bad things with memory (like handling a variable after it has been destroyed) the result is **undefined behavior** and this means something completely different from a "crash".

Undefined behavior means that anything can happen (including a crash) but anything may also mean "nothing". Actually the worst kinds of bug are those in which undefined behavior doesn't do anything apparent immediately, but only to provoke crazy behavior in some other and unrelated and innocent part of the code one million of instructions executed later. Or only when showing your program in front of a vast audience.

So please remember that undefined behavior is not crash. It's a crash only when you're lucky.

The sooner you understand the difference between a bug and a crash and the better it is. Bugs are your enemies, crashes are your friends (because they reveal a bug).

### 2. This code is not doing anything bad

The function returns a `char *`, and this value  (a pointer) is computed by pre-incrementing a local variable. When the function returns the local variable is destroyed, but because the function was returning its **value** (a pointer) then the code is perfectly safe.

It would have been unsafe instead if the function was defined as

```
char *& copyact(char * from)
{
    return ++from;
}
```

because in this case the return value is a **reference** to a pointer to char and it would have returned a reference to `from` that was however going to be already destroyed by the time the caller could access the returned reference.

By the way for exampe `g++` compiler emits a warning when you compile the modified version:

```
vref.cpp: In function ‘char*& copyact(char*)’:
vref.cpp:3:9: warning: reference to local variable ‘from’ returned
```

Note however that even in this case you cannot expect that running the code would generate a crash for sure. For example on my computer running the buggy code with the modified version just prints `"school"` instead of `"chool"`.

It doesn't make much sense, but this is quite normal once you enter Undefined Behavior realm.

Answer (score 2):

It works,  because your function gets the reference to the object that already exists outside of it. The result it returns is just a value. Though judging by the code,  it returns the pointer to the string shifted by one from start. I am not sure that was the idea, also it will probably crash if the original was an empty string.

Comment: Don't we assign a memory location for &from in which it stores the address for string? When the function exits, don't we also destroy the pointer that holds the valid address? or is it because by the time return is executed, the address was already sent to copy= ?

Comment: Function gets the value of the pointer. It increments it and obtains another value, that can be dereferenced as a pointer to the next element. This value it gives back. It will make sense as long as the original pointer still extsts.

Answer (score 1):

```
char * copyact(char * from)
{
    return ++from;
}

    char *string = "school"; 
    char *copy;
    copy = copyact(string);
```

You are making farm points to `"school"` , which is already there in memory

and you are returned from+1 that points to "chool"

For example in which case you should not return.

```
char * copyact(char * from)
 {   
  char a[10];                 //declared array, has automatic scope.
  return a;                  // you should not return a and can't be accessed outside of function. 
 }
```